# For loop not loading all images in pygame and can't blit them onto screen

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a blackjack game and I'm having trouble loading the images for the cards in the for loop. The way that I have named the images is like D4.png is the image for the card 4 of Diamonds and QD.png is the image for the Queen of Diamonds etc. My issue is that only the last card types and numbers are being loaded in. When I check the length of the cards_list, it returns only 8 instead of the 53 cards that will be used.

```
cards_list = []
cards_type_1 = ['D', 'H', 'C', 'S']
cards_type_2 = ['Q', 'K', 'A', 'J']

for card in cards_type_1:
    for x in range(2, 11):
        img = pygame.image.load(f'img\cards\{card}{x}.png')
        cards_list.append(img)

for card in cards_type_2:
    for suit in cards_tpye_1:
        img = pygame.image.load(f'img\cards\{card}{suit}.png')
    cards_list.append(img)

print(len(cards_list)) # This returns only 8
```

Additionally, for the cards that I have loaded, I wish for the computer to deal out these cards at random. I'm using a button module I found online to detect when a button has been clicked. So what I'm trying to do is allow the player to click on the Hit button and be given a card. However, the card only appears on screen for half a second, then disappears.

```
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # this is code for the main menu
    if start_game is False:
        if display_main_menu:
            if exit_btn_1.draw(screen):
                run = False
            if start_btn.draw(screen):
                start_game = True
                # tkinter mainloop
                prompt.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
                root.title('Enter Name')
                e.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3)
                add_btn.grid(row=2, column=1)
                root.mainloop()

            if leaders_btn.draw(screen):
                pass
        
    if start_game is True:
        display_main_menu = False
        if exit_btn_2.draw(screen):
            run = False
        if menu_btn_2.draw(screen):
            start_game = False
            display_main_menu = True
        if hit_btn.draw(screen): # this means if the bit button is clicked
            screen.blit(random.choice(cards_list), (400, 400))
        
        screen.blit(coin_img, (960, 40))

        # draw text method created just to draw text on image
        draw_text(f'Name: {name}', font1, 50, 50, BLACK)
        draw_text(f'Score: {score}', font1, 50, 100, BLACK)
        draw_text(f'{player.credits}', font2, 1050, 50, GOLD)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Yeah, no problem. For the other problem, I suggest you upload full code so anyone can reproduce your bug

Comment: @bilke no, not the entire code, OP should provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the issue causing only 8 cards to be in the list is that `cards_list.append(img)` is outside of the second loop, which causes the entire loop to complete and overwrite `img` every time. The indentation on the line `cards_list.append(img)` should be increased in both loops like so:

```
for card in cards_type_2:
    for suit in cards_tpye_1:
        img = pygame.image.load(f'img\cards\{card}{suit}.png')
        cards_list.append(img)
```

As for the second problem, I believe this is caused by the `if hit_btn.draw(screen):` line. It seems that this function returns True only when the "Hit" button is held down, meaning the card will stop being drawn as soon the button stops being pressed. What you probably want is to have a flag that is set to True inside this if statement instead, and then you can draw the card based on the flag, meaning it won't disappear when the button is no longer pressed.